# Adding Page Attributes Metabox and Page Templates to the Posts Edit Page?

Tags: templates, page-attributes, posts

*(**Moderators note:** Title was originally "How can I add the "Page Attributes" and/or "Page Attributes > Template" selector to POSTS editor")*

WP currently only allows the assignment of a "template" to Pages (i.e. `post_type=='page'`.) I'd like to extend this functionality to Posts as well (i.e. `post_type=='post'`.)

How can I add the *"Page Attributes"* meta box and more specifically, the template switcher to the posts editor?

I'm assuming this is code I will place in my `functions.php` for my theme.

UPDATE: I've managed to add the hardcoded templates pulldown menu to my post editor, by simply adding the select box html to my existing custom meta options box. Here's the code I'm using for that...

```
add_meta_box('categorydiv2', __('Post Options'), 'post_categories_meta_box_modified', 'post', 'side', 'high');
```

And here's the function that writes out the options and the template select box...

```
//adds the custom categories box
function post_categories_meta_box_modified() {
    global $post;
    if( get_post_meta($post->ID, '_noindex', true) ) $noindexChecked = " checked='checked'";
    if( get_post_meta($post->ID, '_nofollow', true) ) $nofollowChecked = " checked='checked'";
?>
<div id="categories-all" class="ui-tabs-panel">
    <ul id="categorychecklist" class="list:category categorychecklist form-no-clear">
        <li id='noIndex' class="popular-category"><label class="selectit"><input value="noIndex" type="checkbox" name="chk_noIndex" id="chk_noIndex"<?php echo $noindexChecked ?> /> noindex</label></li> 
        <li id='noFollow' class="popular-category"><label class="selectit"><input value="noFollow" type="checkbox" name="chk_noFollow" id="chk_noFollow"<?php echo $nofollowChecked ?> /> nofollow</label></li>
    </ul>

    <p><strong>Template</strong></p> 
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="page_template">Post Template</label><select name="page_template" id="page_template"> 
    <option value='default'>Default Template</option> 
    <option value='template-wide.php' >No Sidebar</option>
    <option value='template-salespage.php' >Salespage</option>
    </select>
</div>
<?php
}
```

And finally, the code to capture the selected values on save...

```
function save_post_categories_meta($post_id) {
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return $post_id;
    $noIndex = $_POST['chk_noIndex'];
    $noFollow = $_POST['chk_noFollow'];
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_noindex', $noIndex );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_nofollow', $noFollow );
    return $post_id;
}
```

Now, I believe all that's left is (1) capturing the selected template and adding it to the post meta for this post and (2) modifying index.php and single.php so that it uses the chosen template.

Comment: *@Scott B*: Well I wrote my whole answer before I saw that you were working on it too, and it seems you've taken it in a somewhat different direction that your original question with your no follow and no index options. Hopefully what I did still has value for you. If not, maybe it will help others.

Comment: Yep, you've answered the question. I did take a bit different tack once I realized I didn't need to parse the directory and could hardcode the values for my specific templates. I'll still likely need to borrow some of your code for actually getting WP to use the correct assigned template for the post.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hate to be the bearer of bad news but **WordPress hardcodes the Page Template functionality to the *"page"* post type**, at least in v3.0 *(that might change in future versions but there's not a specific initiative I'm aware of to change it yet. So this is one of the very few times I'm struggling to figure out how to get around something without hacking core.)*

The solution I've come up with is to basically copy the relevant code from WordPress core and modify it to our needs. Here are the steps (the line numbers are from v3.0.1):

1. **Copy the `page_attributes_meta_box()` function** from line 535 of `/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php` and modify to suit.
2. **Code an `add_meta_boxes` hook** to add the metabox created in #1.
3. **Copy the `get_page_templates()` function** from line 166 of `/wp-admin/includes/theme.php` 
   and modify to suit.
4. **Copy the `page_template_dropdown()` function** from line 2550 of `/wp-admin/includes/template.php` and modify to suit.
5. **Add a Post Template** to your theme.
6. **Code a `save_post` hook** to enable storing of the post template file name upon save.
7. **Code a `single_template` hook** to enable loading of the post template for the associated posts.

Now on with it!

---

### 1. Copy the `page_attributes_meta_box()` function

As our first step you need to copy the `page_attributes_meta_box()` function from line 535 of `/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php` and I've chosen to rename it `post_template_meta_box()`. Since you only asked for page templates I omitted the code for specifying a parent post and for specifying the order which makes the code much simpler. I also chose to use postmeta for this rather than try to reuse the `page_template` object property in order to avoid and potential incompatibilities caused by unintentional coupling. So here's the code:

```
function post_template_meta_box($post) {
  if ( 'post' == $post->post_type && 0 != count( get_post_templates() ) ) {
    $template = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_post_template',true);
    ?>
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="post_template"><?php _e('Post Template') ?></label><select name="post_template" id="post_template">
<option value='default'><?php _e('Default Template'); ?></option>
<?php post_template_dropdown($template); ?>
</select>
<?php
  } ?>
<?php
}
```

### 2. Code an `add_meta_boxes` hook

Next step is to add the metabox using the `add_meta_boxes` hook:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes','add_post_template_metabox');
function add_post_template_metabox() {
    add_meta_box('postparentdiv', __('Post Template'), 'post_template_meta_box', 'post', 'side', 'core');
}
```

### 3. Copy the `get_page_templates()` function

I assumed it would only make sense to differentiate between page templates and post template  thus the need for a `get_post_templates()` function based on `get_page_templates()` from line 166 of `/wp-admin/includes/theme.php`. But instead of using the `Template Name:` marker which page templates use this function uses a `Post Template:` marker instead which you can see below.

I also filtered out inspection of `functions.php` *(not sure how `get_page_templates()` ever worked correctly without that, but whatever!)* And the only thing left is to change references to the word `page` to `post` for maintenance readability down the road:

```
function get_post_templates() {
  $themes = get_themes();
  $theme = get_current_theme();
  $templates = $themes[$theme]['Template Files'];
  $post_templates = array();

  if ( is_array( $templates ) ) {
    $base = array( trailingslashit(get_template_directory()), trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory()) );

    foreach ( $templates as $template ) {
      $basename = str_replace($base, '', $template);
      if ($basename != 'functions.php') {
        // don't allow template files in subdirectories
        if ( false !== strpos($basename, '/') )
          continue;

        $template_data = implode( '', file( $template ));

        $name = '';
        if ( preg_match( '|Post Template:(.*)$|mi', $template_data, $name ) )
          $name = _cleanup_header_comment($name[1]);

        if ( !empty( $name ) ) {
          $post_templates[trim( $name )] = $basename;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return $post_templates;
}
```

### 4. Copy the `page_template_dropdown()` function

Similarly copy `page_template_dropdown()` from line 2550 of `/wp-admin/includes/template.php` to create `post_template_dropdown()` and simply change it to call `get_post_templates()` instead:

```
function post_template_dropdown( $default = '' ) {
  $templates = get_post_templates();
  ksort( $templates );
  foreach (array_keys( $templates ) as $template )
    : if ( $default == $templates[$template] )
      $selected = " selected='selected'";
    else
      $selected = '';
  echo "\n\t<option value='".$templates[$template]."' $selected>$template</option>";
  endforeach;
}
```

### 5. Add a Post Template

Next step is to add a post template for testing. Using the `Post Template:` marker mentioned in step #3 copy `single.php` from your theme to `single-test.php` and add the following comment header (*be sure to modify something in `single-test.php` so you can tell it is loading instead of `single.php`)*:

```
/**
 * Post Template: My Test Template
 */
```

Once you've done steps #1 thru #5 you can see your *"Post Templates"* metabox appear on your post editor page:

[image: What a Post Templates Metabox looked like when added to WordPress 3.0]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101010-183833.png))</sub>

### 6. Code a `save_post` hook

Now that you have the editor squared away you need to actually save your page template file name to postmeta when the user clicks "Publish". Here's the code for that:

```
add_action('save_post','save_post_template',10,2);
function save_post_template($post_id,$post) {
  if ($post->post_type=='post' && !empty($_POST['post_template']))
    update_post_meta($post->ID,'_post_template',$_POST['post_template']);
}
```

### 7. Code a `single_template` hook

And lastly you need to actually get WordPress to use your new post templates. You do that by hooking `single_template` and returning your desired template name for those posts that have had one assigned:

```
add_filter('single_template','get_post_template_for_template_loader');
function get_post_template_for_template_loader($template) {
  global $wp_query;
  $post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
  if ($post) {
    $post_template = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_post_template',true);
    if (!empty($post_template) && $post_template!='default')
      $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . "/{$post_template}";
  }
  return $template;
}
```

And that's about it!

**NOTE** that I ***did not*** take into consideration **Custom Post Types**, only `post_type=='post'`. In my opinion addressing custom post types would require differentiating between the different post types and, while not overly difficult, I didn't attempt that here.

Comment: Great! I went to sleep with an almost complete code in my editor with the same approach of copying the default WordPress functions (it was complete, but I would not post it since I didn't test). :)

Comment: *@sorich87* - You know the old saying, *"You snooze, you loose!"*  Seriously though, *ONLY* kidding. There's really only one reasonable way to make it work so it's not wonder your code would be the same!

Comment: Mike, you continue to amaze. Thanks very much for taking the time to hammer this out.

Comment: @sorich87 - Thanks for working on it. I really appreciate the effort.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel: :) it was almost exactly the same. @Scott B: you are welcome!

Comment: *@Scott B*: No problem, glad I could help. I look for reasonably generic questions that could potentially help a lot of people and try to answer them for not only the person asking the question but for those who may come after.

Comment: Anyone know if there is a better solution now in 2016?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress allows you to add Meta to Categories using a plugin:

To do this you need to add one of the various extensions that adds meta to categories (mimicking what pages get out of the box), [Simple Term Meta](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-term-meta/) does the job nicely.

N.B. WordPress 3.x is needed for extending Categories.

After that you can use:

- add_term_meta
- update_term_meta
- get_term_meta

Use Functions.php to add methods to do what you want e.g.

```
add_action('category_add_form_fields', 'category_metabox_add', 10, 1);

function category_metabox_add($tag) { ?>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="image-url"><?php _e('Image URL') ?></label>
        <input name="image-url" id="image-url" type="text" value="" size="40" aria-required="true" />
        <p class="description"><?php _e('This image will be the thumbnail shown on the category page.'); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php } 

add_action('created_category', 'save_category_metadata', 10, 1);

function save_category_metadata($term_id)
{
    if (isset($_POST['image-url'])) 
        update_term_meta( $term_id, 'image-url', $_POST['image-url']);                  
}
```

Calling new fields in themes is easy:

```
<?php echo get_term_meta(get_query_var('cat'), 'image-url', true); ?>
```

More details and examples:
http://www.wphub.com/adding-metadata-taxonomy-terms/