# How do I create a Custom Post Box that Connects Different Posts Together

Tags: customization

In WordPress, I'm trying to create a Custom Post Box that will allow one post to be manually connected to another post.

The easiest way to illustrate this request was to mockup what I would like the final Post Box to look like.  That mockup can be viewed here » http://cl.ly/3hI3

**Requirements:**

- The Post Box needs to resemble the "Categories" Post Box, in that it has tabs at the top and checkboxes.
- Each tab at the top of this Post Box needs to be a Post Category (as illustrated in the mockup.)  If I could manually control this so that the tabs were managed by a Custom Menu (ie. "Post Connections Menu"), that would be ideal.
- The checkboxed list of items needs to be posts that have already been categorized to that specific category.

Thank you very much for any help / insight you can throw my way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Mike -- does it need to be connected to *another post*, or can it be a custom taxonomy or custom field?

Comment: I think the Custom Taxonomy will be the way to go.  Had no idea this feature was even in WP.  Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 0):

You're basically looking for [custom taxonomies (Wordpress Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Taxonomies). Then you need to create a plugin that [adds a meta box to the post editor (Wordpress Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) and lists your taxonomies form therein. The code to create a form for a taxonomy ships with wordpress itself.

Related Question: [Adding Page Attributes Metabox and Page Templates to the Posts Edit Page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2765/adding-page-attributes-metabox-and-page-templates-to-the-posts-edit-page)

Comment: Thanks @hakre for the thoughtful reply.  I'm going to look into Custom Taxonomies!